# how to parse a table without an Id tag using jsoup.

Tags: java, arrays, jsoup

how to parse a table without an Id tag. 
I'm trying to parse a table with source code line 2290 to 3153 http://pastebin.com/DjGHED5t

It isn't obvious to me as to how to do it. what I have now is

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class test{
public static void main (String []args){
    String Ticker = "KO";
    URL url = new URL("http://toolbox.investools.com/graphs/fundamentalAnalysis.iedu?report=BS&symbol="+(Ticker));
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
    Elements table = doc.select(table);
    Iterator<Element> ite = table.select(table[width="100%"] [bgcolor="#CCCCCC"] [cellpadding="0"] [cellspacing="2"]);

        String[][] balanceSheetInfo = new String [46][11];

        while (ite.hasNext()){
            for (int row = 0, row_size = balanceSheetInfo[row].length; row < row_size; row++){
                    for (int col = 0, col_size = balanceSheetInfo.length; col < col_size; col++){
                        if(ite.hasNext()){
                        balanceSheetInfo[col][row] = input.next();
                        System.out.printf("%s",balanceSheetInfo[col][row]);                         }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

But i am getting symbol not found errors.  I am not strong with Jsoup and scraping given this is the first project I have used it in. If someone could guide me it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Read your code:

```
Elements table = doc.select(table);
```

You're using the table variable (in `doc.select(table)`) before it's even declared. The [`Element.select()` method](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) takes a String as argument. You need

```
Elements table = doc.select("table");
```

with double quotes, which will select all the table elements.

The next line has the same problem:

```
table.select(table[width="100%"] [bgcolor="#CCCCCC"] [cellpadding="0"] [cellspacing="2"]);
```

should be

```
table.select("table[width=\"100%\"] [bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"] [cellpadding=\"0\"] [cellspacing=\"2\"]");
```

Comment: if(ite.hasNext()){
    balanceSheetInfo[col][row] = ite.text();System.out.printf("%s",balanceSheetInfo[col][row]);  it says ite.text() method doesnt exist.  maybe compiled wrong?

Comment: also,  it is a site that needs a login, using apache would this compile apaches- i keep getting an invalid flag error?.  javac ;./httpclient-4.2.jar ;./jsoup-1.6.3.jar javac test.java